# Search for text in output and use whatever is behind the text

Tags: php, search

I was wondering how I could search for certain text (ie: description), and use all that's behind that text as a variable (all that is on the same line) in PHP. This needs to be read from an external location, a PHP file that must be ran (the PHP file reads content from a MySQL database and outputs this as a sort of index)

Any help would be appreciated.

Edit to clarify:

Sample input:

```
Lorum ipsum dolor
```

Sample output:

```
dolor
```

Comment: What do you mean, "behind"? Something like looking for 'c' in 'a b c d e f' and returnin 'd e f'?

Comment: Please post sample input and output to help us understand what you want.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do you mean that given this string:

Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat **cupidatat** non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.

```
$wordToFind = "cupidatat";

$allTextBehindWordToFind = substr($str, strpos($str, $wordToFind));

echo $allTextBehindWordToFind; 
// outputs: 'cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.';
```

Or:

```
$allTextBehindWordToFind = substr($str, strpos($str, $wordToFind) + strlen($wordToFind));

echo $allTextBehindWordToFind; 
// outputs: ' non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.';
```

Comment: As for what you said (outputs) it will take the text in front of the word? I would like what is behind the word (after the word)

Comment: Updated my answer accordingly

Comment: edit: Could you also show how it would work if it outputs to a certain word? sample input: "lorem ipsum dolor sit amet" , sample output "dolor" , so it searches for ipsum and sit.

Comment: I don't understand. You want the word before and after the choose word? Please be more clear.

Comment: What i want is to output a certain text in between two words.

Comment: So you want to give 'ipsum' and 'sit' and return the stuff inbetween? `echo substr($str, strpos($str, 'firstword') + strlen('firstword'), strpos($str, 'secondword'))` this however function as desired if 'firstword' or 'secondword' appears more that twice. That's a little more complex and should be a new question.

Answer (score 0):

Alternatively, you could do this:

```
$tail = array_pop(explode($needle, $string, 2));
```

But be sure to check `$tail` against the original string. If `$needle` wasn't found in `$string`, `$tail` will be `$string`.